# How to get entered value in editable ComboBox in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a ComboBox which lists the values set. I have made it editable using setEditable(true) method but how to get the value entered by user? I tried getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() and getValue() method but didn't succeed.

Here is the code.

```
public class Comparator extends Application {

    @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 450, 250);

        ComboBox<String> emailComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        emailComboBox.getItems().addAll("A","B","C","D","E");

        emailComboBox.setEditable(true);        

        Button b = new Button("get text");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Label to = new Label("To: ");
        Label selected = new Label();
        grid.add(to, 0, 0);
        grid.add(emailComboBox, 1, 0);
        grid.add(b, 2, 0);
        grid.add(selected, 3, 0);

        b.setOnAction(e -> {
            selected.setText(emailComboBox.????);
        });

        Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I actually want to get the newly entered value.
PS: Just to avoid the confusion if in case. I can enter any String which doesn't exist in the list already. this will be a new value entered.

Comment: What does "didn't succeed" mean? `emailComboBox.getValue()` should work just fine. What happens?

Comment: When i type in text box and click the button, it displays nothing.

Comment: Are you committing the value by pressing enter after typing it?

Comment: getValue() works after pressing enter. this isn't what i'm looking for. getEditor().getText() works good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, most JavaFX controls don't "commit" a value on losing focus - so `TextField`s, when used as editing controls inside a larger control such as a `ComboBox` don't commit the value back to the parent control unless the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. There is quite a lot of controversy about this design decision: however it is the decision that was made and if we are to use JavaFX we have to either accept that or find ways to work around it to get the behavior we want.

One "quick and dirty" approach would be to dig into the text field and get the text from it, as in @Ajeetkumar's answer:

```
selected.setText(emailComboBox.getEditor().getText());
```

The problem with this approach is that it leaves the application in an inconsistent state: the value displayed to the user in the label is not the value held in the model of the combo box: in other words `emailComboBox.getValue()` returns a different value to the one displayed in the label (since the value from the text field was never committed to the combo box). At some point your application will need to process the data displayed, and the natural place the programmer (or another member of the team) will look for the data is in the combo box's model: i.e. they will expect the data to be in `emailComboBox.getValue()`. A better approach is to make sure the combo box's value updates when you want it to, and then just use the expected `emailComboBox.getValue()` to get the data.

For example, you could update the value when the text field loses focus:

```
    emailComboBox.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
        if (! isNowFocused) {
            emailComboBox.setValue(emailComboBox.getEditor().getText());
        }
    });
```

and then the natural:

```
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        selected.setText(emailComboBox.getValue());
    });
```

With this approach, the application is always in a consistent state: i.e. the label is displaying the value of the combo box, which is far less likely to cause bugs later on than setting the label directly from the text field.

Another variation is to update the combo box value as soon as the text in the editor changes:

```
    emailComboBox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        emailComboBox.setValue(newText);
    });
```

Note that, if you wanted, with this version you could actually dispense with the button entirely and just bind the label's text directly to the combo box's value:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Comparator extends Application {

    @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 450, 250);

        ComboBox<String> emailComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        emailComboBox.getItems().addAll("A","B","C","D","E");

        emailComboBox.setEditable(true);        

        emailComboBox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
            emailComboBox.setValue(newText);
        });


        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Label to = new Label("To: ");
        Label selected = new Label();
        grid.add(to, 0, 0);
        grid.add(emailComboBox, 1, 0);
        grid.add(selected, 2, 0);

        selected.textProperty().bind(emailComboBox.valueProperty());

        Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Keeping the integrity of the data is highly recommended for keeping the application consistent and making it less likely to introduce bugs later on, so it's highly recommended to update the combo box's `value` property to contain the value you want to represent, and then to refer to that value. The text field used as an editor is really an implementation detail of the combo box that should only be used to modify the behavior of the combo box editing process: in this example it's used to modify the update behavior - you could also set a formatter on it, etc. It shouldn't be used as a proxy for the model, as this will make life difficult later.

Comment: @Ajeetkumar since fx9, commit-on-focuslost is default behaviour for all editable input components (combo, spinner, datePicker) - see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150946 For commit-on-typing, you'll still need a changeListener on the editor's textProperty that commits on change as James suggested

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

emailComboBox.getEditor().getText()

The textField where we type in an editable ComboBox is known as the *editor* of the ComboBox. And it's a normal TextField object. To access that object, you need to use the method **ComboBox.getEditor()**. This way you can use the methods of the TextField class.

Comment: don't know why this was down voted. this works for me. no other answers worked for me.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. If the editor hasn't committed the value, then you will be in a situation where the text in the label is different to the value held by the combo box. Since you are aiming for the label's text to be equal to the combo box's value, this essentially means your application is in an inconsistent state. Whether or not this causes actual problems depends on what your application is doing and on your actual requirements, but even if the current requirements don't make this an issue, you may add functionality later and find this causes issues.

Comment: The case you mentioned is in fact happens with getValue(). if I use getValue() we are required to press enter to commit value. whereas getEditor.getText() doesn't require an enter key, it works even If i just type and click the button. did you try this?

Comment: I did try it. It only "works" in the very narrow sense that it updates the label to the value you want. The problem is that it doesn't update the combo box's `value` property, so your application is now in an inconsistent state. The point is that you are going to want to process the data at some point (send to a database, send an email, do something) and when you do, the label is not where you will expect to find your data - you (or another programmer on your team) will expect it to be in the combo box's model, i.e. in the `value` property. You should ensure that `value` is updated instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the list as you change the editor value

```
pluginConfig.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        if (pluginConfig.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() >= 0)
            pluginConfig.getItems().set(pluginConfig.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),newText);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line of code to get the selected value in the `ComboBox`, and set in on the `Label`:

```
selected.setText(emailComboBox.getValue());
```

Since you're using strings, you should also set the parameterized type of the `ComboBox` as follows:

```
ComboBox<String> emailComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
```

Comment: Did you fix the type of the `ComboBox` as suggested? It will not work if you don't do that.

Comment: Using getValue() requires me to press enter to commit the value. Then it works after I click the button. but this isn't what i want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String surName=cmbSurName.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
System.out.println(surName);
```